# Oracle:Why is select from user_ind_columns so slow?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-metadata

Oracle version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

I'm trying to get metadata from my Oracle database (I'm a bit of a noob at Oracle, more of a Sybase man). When I do

```
select * from USER_IND_COLUMNS
```

it takes 4 minutes 41 seconds to return just 7211 rows! Can anyone tell me why this should be? In fact, getting metadata generally (in Toad or otherwise) seems incredibly slow. All suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: sounds like it may be bad dictionary statistics. have you tried dbms_stats.gather_dictionary_stats at all?

Comment: Thanks DazzaL. I'll see what I can get done.